# How do determine whether an entry in a Blockchain was submitted by myself?

Tags: cryptography

Let say I have a Blockchain id `id` as below:-

```
id = "285a2d215ea5a866cbe38ba2f5de58e5ac497ed4984f31fa0307a5c3c5539f47"
BlockchainGet[id]
```

I want to check whether `id` was previously submitted by myself. How can I check it? That would be even better if I can check when did I submit it.

Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe with [`BlockchainTransactionData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockchainTransactionData.html)? I don’t really know much about blockchain functionality though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlockchainPut writes an expression to the Wolfram blockchain but there's no signing involved, so no way to prove that you made that transaction. Note that blockchain functions are marked as experimental and that means they can change between releases. V12 introduced new blockchain functionalities focused on Bitcoin and Ethereum. You can see examples here:

https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/blockchain/?product=mathematica